# internal server error when deploying NextJs to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, next.js

I have deployed my NextJS project (adapted from https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-firebase-hosting) to firebase, but when i browse to the URL i get "Internal Server Error".

Deployment did run through successfully:

```
i  deploying database, functions, hosting
+  database: rules ready to deploy.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing src/functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged src/functions (571.83 KB) for uploading
+  functions: src/functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting: preparing src/public directory for upload...
!  Warning: Public directory does not contain index.html

i  Progress: [....................................................................................................]

+  hosting: 3 files uploaded successfully
i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...
i  functions: updating function next...
+  functions[next]: Successful update operation.
+  functions: all functions deployed successfully!

+  Deploy complete!
```

So i feel perhaps it is something to do with the structure of my project? Or firebase.json config? Could someone have a look and let me know?

Here is my firebase.json which is in the root of my project:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "src/functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "src/public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**/**",
        "function": "next"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that since this blog was published, there has been some major changes in the GCF architecture. I've been getting the same error also. At the moment, this is incompatible.

Comment: same here, I also got the error: page not found, even I have a placeholder.html under public folder. Could anyone help please?